# Is it possible to install ubuntu on an X86 android tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, intel-atom

I have an intel tablet model TM75A that has an Intel Atom processor. This tablet has an Android operating system and does not support dual boot. It is possible to install ubuntu on this tablet. Thanks